# 400 Bad request error in Ajax call to Spring controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to send data to Spring controller but i am recieving 400 badrequest error in browser console.
here is my code:

javascript:

```
function insertDiscussion(title, content,tags) {
    $.ajax({
        async:false,
        url: 'save',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            "title": title,
            "content": content,
            "tags":tags
        },
        success: function(data) {
            generateNoty(data, "warning");
        }
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveDiscussion(
        @RequestParam String title,
        @RequestParam String content, @RequestParam(value="tags") String[] tags) {
    return "hello";
}
```

Example is working if we dont send array. When i am trying to send array its giving 400 Bad Request error.

If I access same controller with links its working fine but its not working with jquery ajax. did i missed anything?

Comment: FYI `async: false` is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I tried with and without async: false . but its not working.

Comment: @igniter that is not what he meant to say

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're expecting `@RequestParam` (`POST`/`GET` parameter) but sending `JSON` as request body. You need to use `@RequestBody` instead.

Try

```
public String saveDiscussion(@RequestBody Map json) {
    return "hello";
}
```

See also:

- http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html
- http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-consumes

Comment: I am using spring mvc 3.1.1 and there is no package available for @RequestModel annotation. Is there new annotation for that. I did not find anything on google so far regarding that.

Comment: my bad, sorry. its `@RequestBody`. And another this - i've never tried `@RequestBody` with `Map`, usually it's some class with fields to be mapped from request. but believe Spring can use Map also